# Should image URL slugs use the article URL slug, or their own description slug for SEO?

Tags: seo, wordpress, images, url-slug, thumbnail

I have a WordPress website.  The slug of my articles is automatically generated from the title and the same slug is also used for image thumbnails.  The titles and slugs are in Arabic.

Should thumbnail slugs have the same or close slug to my article slug for SEO? Instead, can I just describe the image itself in the slug and leave the article title out of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Describing the image yourself would be much better from SEO point of view.

Article title always won't be matching the image contents. It would be manual work to describe the image and use that image name or alt tags but that is worth it.

Don't forget that you can easily target Google Image search as a traffic source if your image appears in that search results and is relevant to the query made by the user.